# Question regarding the creation of an credit_card object on Ryan bates Active_Merchant intergration video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I was going through Ryan Bates' video on Active Merchant integration video Railscast #145 and my question was regarding the creation of the @credit_card method that he defines within the Order.rb method.

```
def credit_card
  @credit_card||=ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
    :type=>card_type,
    :number=>card_number,
    :verification_value=>card_verification,
    :month=>card_expires_on.month,
    :year=>card_expires_on.year,
    :first_name=>first_name,
    :last_name=>last_name
  )
```

end

What I don't follow is how does this method get called. The form_for in the new method creates an @order object while and there is no mention of the credit_card method. How does the credit_card method get called to initiate the creation of the @credit_card object.

I am aware of virtual attributes but I dont know how the credit_card method is actually called.

Comment: i think i just figured it out. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screencast code [here](http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-145/).

**In app/views/orders/new.html.erb**

We can see the order form, and from the first line

```
<% form_for @order do |f| %>
```

We see that, on submission, the form use the oders_controller create method.

**In app/controller/orders_controller.rb**

```
    def create
      @order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
      @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip

      if @order.save
        if @order.purchase
          render :action => "success"
        else
          render :action => "failure"
        end
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
```

We can see that @order is Order instance built from the cart. Nothing special here
This order is now saved with `@order.save` and then the purchase method is called on @order

Let's take a look at this purchase method!

**in app/model/order.rb**

```
    def purchase
      response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
      transactions.create!(:action => "purchase", :amount => price_in_cents, :response => response)
      cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now) if response.success?
      response.success?
    end
```

Second line `response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)`
. The credit_card method is called there as an argument of GATEWAY.purchase